# Mining text with small datasets

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining, natural-language, small-sample

I'm interning in an auditing company and have audit reports that require categorising. I have been using simple text mining + classification techniques in R (`DocumentTermMatrix` in `tm` package, SVM via `e1071` package, etc.) to help.

Unfortunately it is laborious to manually categorise the issues to create the train data, but as of now I have about **50+** samples categorised into about **7** categories. A shockingly small number, I know.

What then is the best way to continue? Is 50 too small a size for training data? I have about 150 reports that requires categorising. The reports are each roughly about 900 - 2000 chars (1-2 pages) long (hence laborious to manually categorize).

Comment: Honestly, I'd stick to categorizing them by-hand, or preparing some heuristic rules to categorize them (e.g. existence of some particular terms in documents etc).

Comment: yes, i've thought about heuristics (e.g. certain terms coming up) but it is hard to come up with rigid rules because everyone writes differently and the presence of a term (e.g. "inaccurate") does not determine the report's category (e.g. "inaccurate report")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [latent semantic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis)? Maybe you will be able to find meaningful patterns when you visualize the data in 2 or 3 dimensions.

If you have mostly unlabeled data then maybe you can leverage it using semi-supervised approach, for example [label propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Label_Propagation_Algorithm).